# SiteMap / webmaster / google adsense

Tags: google-search-console, google-adsense, xml-sitemap

Can we apply for Adsense without sending Sitemap to webmaster tools ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to send a sitemap?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
Here are the published AdSense [requirements](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9724), [policies](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48182), and [terms](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms). The word "sitemap" never appears. Nor does a sitemap seem to have any obvious relevance to AdSense, since the ads are based on the pages the ads *appear in* not some overall spidering of the site.

Your demand for "100% correct knowledge" suggests you have some doubts about this. Maybe you should explain why you're asking in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Adsense required some geniune content and sizeable content in your website. site wap not required for adSense